# what is the error for this statement written in jquery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, syntax-error

I am now writing javascript code, and one of the statement is :`if(($(this).find("option").filter(":selected").length > 0)`. On Chrome and Firefox, it is ok. but on ie8, it keeps telling me that 'syntax error', some guy can help me with this?

ps: because of my carelessness, i wrote an extra $, i modified the above code. now the problem is right now.

Comment: sorry, there should be just one $ in the problem description

Comment: and a single bracket as well.

Comment: and a single bracket but do not understand why chrome and FF ignore that.

Comment: sorry, I am just wasting your time. I should have put the question clear and correct. there is just one bracket. but the problem is still there

Answer (score 3):

you are having one extra ($

```
if($($(this).find("option").filter(":selected").length > 0)
```

should be

```
if ( $(this).find("option").filter(":selected").length > 0 )
```

Comment: sorry, there should be just one $ in the problem description

Answer (score 1):

> instead of   $($(this)

use  `$(this)`

Comment: sorry, there should be just one $ in the problem description